# Getting the next element of a list on a function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to return the next element in a list on a function call, this is what I have tried so far:

```
from itertools import cycle
def get_next_element():
    lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    cycle_list = cycle(lst)
    return next(cycle_list)
```

Now when I call the above function:

```
while True:
    x = get_next_element() # x should return 1, 2, 3
```

But x is always returned as 1 every time the function is called within the loop.

Comment: Your `get_next_element()` function creates a `cycle(lst)` every time you call it, so it naturally starts with `1` every time.

Comment: @quamrana ahh thanks, I have created cycle(lst) variable outside the function and now it works :-)

Comment: I don't see the point of your `getNextElement()` function. If you want to loop over the array just use `for i in lst` and if you want to create an infinite loop, loop over `for i in cycle(lst)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `cycle` in order to make it callable.

```
from itertools import cycle

class mycycle(cycle):
    def __call__(self):
        return next(self)
```

Demo:

```
>>> get_next_element = mycycle([1, 2, 3])
>>> get_next_element()
1
>>> get_next_element()
2
>>> get_next_element()
3
>>> get_next_element()
1
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive solution